# Matrix Entry URL Link

Tags: matrix, url, entry

Trying to create a page link to entries and can't figure out how to do it.  Here's what I have.  It's just outputting the title, but not the url.  Specifically, I'm talking about `{{ block.pageLink.first }}` Any help is much appreciated.

```
{% for block in entry.threeHomepageImages.type('images') %}
    <div class="col">
        <div class="image-block">
            <div class="image">
                {% if block.image|length %}
                    <a href="{{ block.pageLink.first }}">
                        <img src="images/{{ block.image.first }}.jpg" alt="{{ block.alt }}">
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <h1><a href="#">{{ block.imageTitle }}</a></h1>

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I assume 'threeHomepageImages' is the Matrix field and 'image' is an Assets field?  What type of field is 'pageLink'?

Comment: It's an Entries field...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `pageLink` is an Entry field and `image` is an Assets field, then you're probably looking for something like this:

```
<a href="{{ block.pageLink.first().getUrl() }}">
    <img src="{{ block.image.first().getUrl() }}" alt="{{ block.alt }}">
</a>
```